# Read from borg backup repository without authentication passphrase

Tags: archive, borgbackup

Borg Backup always asks for the key passphrase when accessing a repository which was initialized in *authenticated* or *authenticated-blake2* mode (see [borg manual](http://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/init.html?highlight=authenticated)).

However, it should in principle be possible to read data from such a repository **without** knowing the passphrase (albeit without any authentication guarantees). Does borg offer a way of doing so?

Comment: To decrypt encrypted data, you will need to be in possession of the key.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I'm aware of that. But in *authenticated* mode, borg does not encrypt the data, the key is only used to generate and verify HMACs for cryptographic integrity checking.

Answer (score 1):

> Does borg offer a way of doing so?

I am unaware of this capability within borgbackup.

You are correct that there is a theoretical possibility/likelihood the data is readable because it isn't actually *encrypted* -- simply hashed for integrity verification.

This *does not* mean the application has a mechanism for doing so, which is what your question is actually asking. The documentation does not indicate anything like this functionality.

I assume you are interested in accessing the data regardless if borgbackup itself actually has the functionality. If yes, read on.

["That is not possible" is a valid answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/that-is-not-possible-is-a-valid-answer) --
This doesn't mean you are out of luck reading the data, but you are probably not going to use borgbackup tools if you succeed. I would suggest applying standard search, text processing, expression matching, etc. tactics to the data on disk that borgbackup has archived, and see what you can come up with.